# Excel 2010 interop defining in-line XML Styles

Tags: .net, xml, excel, interop

In .net you can create excel sheets programmatically. You can define a style like this:

```
<Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
     <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/MM/yy"/>
 </Style>
```

And assign that style to a cell.

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="DateLiteral">
   <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2017-01-20T00:00:00</Data>
</Cell>
```

Instead of assigning a static date style to all date cells, I rather would like to set each style dynamically.

I found no way to define the Style within the Cell node.  How do I do this?